# I need a macro that will check new entries if it is already existing or it is within the range of an existing entry

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 files with name NewEntries.CSV and Existing.CSV

```
Header A1(Company Code), B1(PurchaseOrg),C1(TransactionType),D1(CommodityCode),E1(MinTC),F1(MaxTC)
```

how will I implement this condition to check the New Entries and copy same or within the range entries in a new file or sheet.

```
IF [NewEntries(A1,B1,C1,D1) = Existing(A1,B1,C1,D1:A*,B*,C*,D*)] & [NewEntries(E1)>= Existing(E*) OR NewEntries(F1)<= Existing(F*)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your logic first.
Put that code below in a new workbook. (Code may be shorten. To see the logic this is better.)

```
Private Sub FindNews()
    Dim intRowE As Long
    Dim intRowN As Long
    Dim intRowD As Long

    Dim Existing As Workbook
    Dim NewEntries As Workbook

    Dim WorksheetExisting
    Dim WorksheetNewEntries

    Application.ScreenUpdating = false

    Set Existing = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Existing.csv")
    Set NewEntries = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\NewEntries.csv")

    Set WorksheetExisting = Existing.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set WorksheetNewEntries = NewEntries.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    intRowD = 1

    For intRowN = 2 To WorksheetNewEntries.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For intRowE = 2 To WorksheetExisting.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If (WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 1).Value = WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 1).Value _
                    And WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 2).Value = WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 2).Value _
                    And WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 3).Value = WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 3).Value _
                    And WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 4).Value = WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 4).Value) _
                    And (WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 5).Value >= WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 5).Value _
                    Or WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 6).Value <= WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 6).Value) Then

                Range("A" & CStr(intRowD) & ":F" & CStr(intRowD)).Value = WorksheetExisting.Range("A" & CStr(intRowN) & ":F" & CStr(intRowN)).Value
                intRowD = intRowD + 1
                Exit For

             End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = true

    Existing.Close SaveChanges:=False
    NewEntries.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@kitap mitap
I have run this code but encountered subscript error in

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(intRowD, 1).Value = WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 1).Value
```

Here is the complete Code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    '
    ' Button1_Click Macro
    '
    Dim intRowE As Long
    Dim intRowN As Long
    Dim intRowD As Long

    Dim Existing As Workbook
    Dim NewEntries As Workbook

    Dim WorksheetExisting As Worksheet
    Dim WorksheetNewEntries As Worksheet

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim strFile As String, strDir As String

    strDir = "C:\Users\john.michael.a.bunyi\Desktop\FR044 Testing\"
    strFile = Dir(strDir & "Acc_FR044_SAP.csv")

    Do While strFile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strDir & strFile, Local:=True)
    wb.SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".csv", ".xls"), FileFormat:=xlExcel8
    wb.Close True

    Set wb = Nothing
    strFile = Dir
    Loop

    strDir = "C:\Users\john.michael.a.bunyi\Desktop\FR044 Testing\"
    strFile = Dir(strDir & "Acc_FR044_SAP - New Entries.csv")

    Do While strFile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strDir & strFile, Local:=True)
    wb.SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".csv", ".xls"), FileFormat:=xlExcel8
    wb.Close True

    Set wb = Nothing
    strFile = Dir
    Loop

    Set Existing = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\john.michael.a.bunyi\Desktop\FR044 Testing\Acc_FR044_SAP.xls")
    Set NewEntries = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\john.michael.a.bunyi\Desktop\FR044 Testing\Acc_FR044_SAP - New Entries.xls")

    Set WorksheetExisting = Existing.Worksheets("Acc_FR044_SAP")
    Set WorksheetNewEntries = NewEntries.Worksheets("Acc_FR044_SAP - New Entries")

    intRowD = 1

    For intRowN = 2 To WorksheetNewEntries.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For intRowE = 2 To WorksheetExisting.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            If (WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 1).Value = WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 1).Value _
                    And WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 2).Value = WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 2).Value _
                    And WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 3).Value = WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 3).Value _
                    And WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 4).Value = WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 4).Value) _
                    And (WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 5).Value >= WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 5).Value _
                    Or WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 6).Value <= WorksheetExisting.Cells(intRowE, 6).Value) Then

                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(intRowD, 1).Value = WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 1).Value
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(intRowD, 2).Value = WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 2).Value
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(intRowD, 3).Value = WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 3).Value
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(intRowD, 4).Value = WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 4).Value
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(intRowD, 5).Value = WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 5).Value
                ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(intRowD, 6).Value = WorksheetNewEntries.Cells(intRowN, 6).Value
                intRowD = intRowD + 1

             End If
        Next
    Next

    Workbooks("Acc_FR044_SAP.xls").Close
    Workbooks("Acc_FR044_SAP - New Entries.xls").Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited the code where is generating error. Just use `Cells...` not `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells...` (And, yes your files are `csv`s)

Comment: @kitapmitap thanks a lot it works!!!! Can you suggest a way tp improve its performance when it is generating the datas? :)

Comment: I have edited my code for a little improvenment. There may be excel functions but in another context not this looping solution.

Comment: An `Exit For` can be added if there is just one `Existing` with a `NewEntry` at the end of the condition. Also `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` can be added.